# I am trying to write a function where arr1[0] = arr2[0], arr1[1] = arr2[1], ... and so on. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function where arr1[0] = arr2[0], arr1[1] = arr2[1], ... and so on. 
How do I do this?

```
// declare both arrays
var list = ["C#", "D#", "F#", "G#", "A#"];
var bar = ["Dd", "Ee", "Gg", "Aa", "Bb"];

// loop through both arrays to check if function has equivalence at i
function getEquivalent(note) {
    for (var i; i=0; i++) {
        if(list[i] === note) {
            return bar[i];
        } else if (bar[i] === note) {
            return note[i];
        } 
    }
}

// it is returning "undefined"
```

Comment: What are you passing as the value of *note*? Because `note[i]` doesn't make much sense, what do you think it should do? If you pass say "Gg" then it will attempt to return `'Gg'[2]` which will be undefined.

Comment: You should set it up on codepen and then you might get some great forked responses.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop doesn't make much sense. I imagine you wanted to write it like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
```

Then, your code works just fine